# alternatives for odd # of players in hand and foot canasta

Tags: canasta, hand-and-foot

Can we have a dummy score for a fourth player instead of having to play on our own?

It is hard when there are 11 players.

Comment: Is there an issue with playing a round with 3 players that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

I have a few ideas off the top of my head.

First, one thing we have done in the past is to have one of the "more experienced" players play multiple hands.  It is a little complicated because that person has to pull double duty.

If you go this route, you may also want to try and not have the person play their two hands right after each other.  This way there is no issues with the person discarding something from hand 1 that hand 2 desperately needs.

I have been the 2 handed person a few times, and the extra effort sometimes makes it seem like I am paying more attention to the game and not in having fun with the people around me.

Another option would be to have somebody sit out each hand.  Maybe two people can share one "seat".  This gives somebody (like the host) to get up and check on everyone and all of that kind of stuff.

Last, invite somebody new to the group.  The more the merrier!

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the player who plays for two players from using one hand to benefit the other? Or picking one hand with no chance of winning to intentionally mess up the player after them?

Comment: Not really.  You kind of have to trust the player.  As I mentioned, one way is to not have the player playing the two hands one immediately after the other.  This way the player can't throw away something form hand A that benefits hand B.  Other than that, it is just trust.